# Notepad++:Searching an regex-expression n times

Tags: regex, notepad++

the text:

```
aaa
```

the regex:

```
a{2}
```

the answer of notepad++ (v5.9.6.2 (UNICODE)):
**Can't find the text "a{2}"**

How can I realize this expression (searching n times) in notepad++?

Comment: Maybe it requires backslashes before this operator, have you tried `a\{2\}`?

Comment: Thanks for your help. in this time i would only find a{2}, because the { and } is escaped and handles as a ordinary character.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**UPDATE:** as of Notepad++ 6.x which now uses PCRE as its regex engine, your given expression should now work as is.

Notepad++ older than 6.0 doesn't support number quantifiers in its regex engine. You'll have to make do with `aa` (repeating the input n times).

Comment: I want to run this on an csv-file.

Comment: I want to run this on an csv-file. it seems, that np++ only provides 10 variables, addrese with /n. so i only make parenthis where i need them.

Comment: but: on this string: "val1;val2;val3;val4;val5;val6;val7;val8;val9;val10;val11;val12;val13;val14;val1;val2;val3;val4;val5;val6;val7;val8;val9;val10;val11;val12;val13;val14;val1;val2;val3;val4;val5;val6;val7;val8;val9;val10;val11;val12;val13;val14;val1;val2;val3;val4;val5;val6;val7;val8;val9;val10;val11;val12;val13;val14;" I can run this "^([^;]+);[^;]+;([^;]+);[^;]+;([^;]+);[^;]+;([^;]+);[^;]+;([^;]+);[^;]+;([^;]+);[^;]+;([^;]+);[^;]+;([^;]+);[^;]+;[^;]+;[^;]+;[^;]+;[^;]+;[^;]+;[^;]+;[^;]+;[^;]+;[^;]+;[^;]+;[^;]+;[^;]+;" (28 times), but not 29 times. D'Oh!

Comment: that is what me caused to do this with the n-times-expression. if i'm right, i can not repeat n times, i can only repeat 28 times, not more.

Comment: Well, looks like that'll be a problem... I don't think I can help much on that.

Comment: So is there no way to search for a pattern 2 or times? Like find 2 or more contiguous spaces?

Comment: @TheSavo: "n or more" is OK. For 2 or more spaces, just search for `\s\s+`.

Comment: @Johannes Veit: If you can update your Notepad++ to 6.1 (the current latest version), please do so, as quantifiers will then finally work :)

Comment: GREAT!!! @BoltClock, it really works right now... just for the record: "[^;]*\;" catches a single entry of a csv-record (for example "val1;"). if i close the "[^;]"-part in brackets like "([^;])*\;" i can refer the "val1"-part with the replacement-string "\1". bigger example: csv-string "val1;val2;val3;val4;val5;val6;val7;val8;val9;val10;" search-string "^([^;]*)\;[^;]*\;[^;]*\;[^;]*\;[^;]*\;[^;]*\;[^;]*\;[^;]*\;[^;]*\;([^;]+)\;" and replacement-string "\1;\2" returns "val1;val10" YEHAAAW :)